# How to communicate multiple containers with each other in Docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, architecture, devops

I'm trying to containerize my application. I use mongodb and 2 more micro services.
As you can see in the docker compose file below, I have some problems.

My requirements:

- *main_image* needs to connect to MongoDB.
- *gui_image* needs to connect to MongoDB.
- *gui_image* needs to show its GUI on port 8080 (Can use another port as well)
- *gui_image* has to read and write to a file inside my computer.
- MongoDB has to access a volume inside my computer.
- *main_image* needs access to the internet.

Here is my questions:

1- Does exposing ports in docker file and docker-compose the same thing?

2- How do I mount a volume to mongodb as best practice?

3- How to accomplish the requirements above with the diagram below in docker-compose?

[image]

Here is my **docker-compose** file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    
  main_image:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: .\my_project\dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  gui_image:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: .\my_gui\dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 27017:27017
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

Here is my **dockerfile** under **my_gui** directory:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install dash
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 27017

ENTRYPOINT [ "python","gui_script.py"]
```

And lastly, here is my **dockerfile** under **my_project** directory:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 27017
ENTRYPOINT [ "python","main_script.py"]
```

Answer (score 3):

1.The `EXPOSE` instruction in `Dockerfile` informs Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime(like when using `docker run -p` command).

However using `ports` in compose is a dynamic way of specifying these ports. So images like `nginx` or `apache` which are always supposed to run on port 80 inside the container will use `EXPOSE` in Dockerfile itself.

While an image which has dynamic port which may be controlled using an environment variable will then use expose in docker run or compose file.

```
some_webapi:

environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:80
build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

2.As documented on the docker hub page for mongo image (https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) you can use

```
volumes:
  - '/path/to/your/pc/folder:/path/inside/docker'
```

3.And for the last question you might wanna use Networking in Compose.

By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

Services can join networks like this

```
gui_image:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: .\my_gui\dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 27017:27017
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - gui
```

And also you have to define all the networks used by services in global scope of compose file

```
version: '3'

services:

networks:
   gui:
```

After that containers will be able to see each other even by their `container_name` which you can define in services

```
   mongo:
     image: mongo:latest
     ports:
       - 27017:27017
     container_name: gui_mogno
```

then you will be able to connect to mongo with a connection string like this `mongodb://gui_mogno:27017/`

You can get more information about networking [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: For the networking setup, I'd suggest relying on the `default` network Compose provides for you, and use the service names like `mongo` as host names.  You don't need to manually provide `networks:` or `container_name:`.  This is described further in the _Networking in Compose_ link you provide at the end.